# Toggle the custom button text using highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there any way to toggle the custom button text in highcharts?

```js
toggleButton: {
                text: 'ON',
                onclick: function () {
                    console.log($(this).text());
                    $(this).text(function (i, text) {
                        return text === "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";
                    });
                }
            }
```

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/santoshgiridhar/knmb38dy/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in callback refers to the chart itself. Buttons are stored in `chart.exportSVGElements` array. So, here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/knmb38dy/1/

```js
                toggleButton: {
                    text: 'ON',
                    onclick: function () {
                        var button = this.exportSVGElements[0], // 0 = text element, 1 = rect button
                            $button = $(button.element); // in "element" stored is reference to the DOM object
                            text = $button.text() == "ON" ? "OFF" : "ON";

                        button.attr({
                            text: text
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Note using Highcharts built-in method `attr()` for updating text, not jQuery's `text()`.

**Edit:**

For Highcharts 4.2.3+ use the solution below: http://jsfiddle.net/knmb38dy/33/

The only difference is how to get button in jQuery: `$button = $(button.element.lastChild)`.

Comment: unable to get the link working. Nothing happens on clicking the On link. Can you please suggest

Comment: Thanks! Updated answer for 4.2.x versions.